# Bamboo CI Server - how to configure PHPUnit testing

Tags: php, continuous-integration, phpunit, bamboo

i would like to set up Bamboo CI Server. I've created two stages:

- Stage 1: "Code checkout" with code checkout.
- Stage 2: "PHPunit" with testing via phpunit.

Stage 1 is OK, but on stage 2 I have an error. In Build Log I have:

```
Starting task 'PHPUnit Testing' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.php:task.builder.phpunit'
12-paź-2014 10:45:49    
Beginning to execute external process for build 'CCP - CI - Unit Testing Build - Default Job #4 (CCPCI-UTB-JOB1-4)'
... running command line:
/usr/local/bin/phpunit --log-junit test-reports/phpunit.xml --coverage-html test-reports/coverage/html --bootstrap /var/www/html/ccp/core/tests/bootstrap.php --no-configuration /var/www/html/ccp/core/tests
... in: /home/bamboo/bamboo_home/xml-data/build-dir/CCPCI-UTB-JOB1
12-paź-2014 10:45:49    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11
12-paź-2014 10:45:49    Content-type: text/html
12-paź-2014 10:45:49    
12-paź-2014 10:45:49    Failing task since text 'OK' was not found in last 250 log entries
12-paź-2014 10:45:49    Parsing test results...
12-paź-2014 10:45:49    Finished task 'PHPUnit Testing'
```

If in server terminal I execute phpunit command (/usr/local/bin/phpunit --log-junit test-reports/phpunit.xml --coverage-html test-reports/coverage/html --bootstrap /var/www/html/ccp/core/tests/bootstrap.php --no-configuration /var/www/html/ccp/core/tests), everything is correct (there is OK response).

What's wrong with this?

On the overview screen of build there are two errors:

1. `(Job results summary) No failed tests found, a possible compilation error occurred.`
2. `(Error summary)  Could not find test result reports in the /home/bamboo/bamboo_home/xml-data/build-dir/CCPCI-UTB-JOB1 directory.`

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I have resolved my problem. I had to add an environment variable (JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="-Datlassian.bamboo.builder.successMarker='OK'") to file setenv.sh. Everything works very well.

Comment: Answer your own question with this information (and pretty formatting) and accept your own answer to mark the question as resolved. It may make you wait until tomorrow to actually accept it.

Comment: This question still lists as unsolved. Any chance we can fix that? In case the suggestion of Will was too much hassle: it is now as simple as clicking a button...

Answer (score 0):

Solution as posted by OP in comments:

> I have resolved my problem.
>
> I had to add an environment variable to file `setenv.sh`:
>
> ```
> JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="-Datlassian.bamboo.builder.su‌​ccessMarker='OK'"
> ```
>
> Everything works very well.